# Apollo Store Share State Between Components

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I have a header that switches between displaying `Login/Signup` links, to a `Logout` state depending on whether it can query the user object (basically indicating if there's a jwt in header).

Here's where I'm stuck: on page load, the Header component fetches user info, if it does *not* return data then I know to show the `Login/Signup` links.

So, I click on the Login link, fill out the form and successfully log in. What I want to happen is that to trigger the Header to refetch User information. Ideally, it would check the local cache from the user info returned from logging in.

I'm used to the Redux frame of mind so I feel like I'm missing something fundamental about Apollo state management.

here's a sample of the code:
Header.js

```
const USER_QUERY = gql`
  {
    user {
      id
      email
    }
  }
`;

const LOGOUT_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation LogoutMutation {
    logout {
      message
    }
  }
`;

const Header = () => (
  <div className="header">
    header

    <Query query={USER_QUERY}>
      {({ loading, error, data }) => {
        if (loading) return <div>Fetching</div>;
        if (error) {
          return (
            <div>
              <Link to="signup">Signup</Link>
              <Link to="login">Login</Link>
            </div>
          );
        }

        return (
          <div>
            {data.user.email}
            <Mutation
              mutation={LOGOUT_MUTATION}
            >
              {
                mutation => <button type="submit" onClick={mutation}>Logout</button>
              }
            </Mutation>
          </div>
        );
      }}
    </Query>

  </div>
);
```

Auth.js

```
const SIGNUP_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation SignupMutation($name: String!, $email: String!, $password: String!) {
    signup(name: $name, email: $email, password: $password) {
      id
      name
      email
    }
  }
`;

const LOGIN_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation LoginMutation($email: String!, $password: String!) {
    login(email: $email, password: $password) {
      id
      name
      email
    }
  }
`;

class Auth extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      name: '',
      isSignup: props.type === 'SIGNUP',
    };
  }

  render() {
    const {
      email,
      password,
      name,
      isSignup,
    } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{isSignup ? 'Sign Up' : 'Log In'}</h1>

        <Mutation
          mutation={isSignup ? SIGNUP_MUTATION : LOGIN_MUTATION}
          variables={isSignup ? { name, email, password } : { email, password }}
          onCompleted={(res) => { console.log('complete', res); }}
        >
          {
            (mutation, { error }) => (
              <form
                onSubmit={(e) => {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  mutation();
                }}
              >
                {
                  isSignup
                  && (
                    <React.Fragment>
                      <label htmlFor="auth-name">name</label>
                      <input
                        value={name}
                        onChange={e => this.setState({ name: e.target.value })}
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="name"
                        id="auth-name"
                      />
                    </React.Fragment>
                  )
                }
                <label htmlFor="email">email</label>
                <input
                  value={email}
                  onChange={e => this.setState({ email: e.target.value })}
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="email"
                  id="auth-email"
                />

                <label htmlFor="password">password</label>
                <input
                  value={password}
                  onChange={e => this.setState({ password: e.target.value })}
                  type="password"
                  placeholder="password"
                  id="auth-password"
                />

                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                { error && <div>ERROR Authenticating</div>}
              </form>
            )
          }
        </Mutation>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `Header` component, you should not be using the `error` parameter of the `Query` component to detect if the user is logged in. This parameter is for handling graphql errors, server errors and **should not be a "normal" execution path** in your application.

Now, you must decide what to do with the "isLoggedIn" state before trying to query it.

From what I understood, you decided that your "isLoggedIn" state was stored in the url. Put otherwise, the single source of truth that tells you if a user is logged in or not, is in the URL.

From there, you have various storage options, each with benefits and drawbacks that I will not discuss here:

- Keep it in the url
- Store it in localstorage
- Use a jwt cookie
- Use a [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)
- Use [apollo-link-state](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/state.html)
- ...any other storage option that will become the "source of truth"

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the logged in state is in the URL, but I have an httpOnly secure JWT cookie with user id in the header. However, the client needs a way to test if the user is logged in, thus I send a query to the backend for a logged in user.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what you should not do :) You need to test that the user is logged in with another method that do not involve the error path of a query

Comment: Cool, ya but that's what I'm struggling with. What is that test? And how does the app know globally that that test passed or failed?

Comment: You first need to define the single source of truth for this state (this data). If you want to keep it in the url, the test might be something like `const isLoggedIn = doesURLHaveValidJWT()`